# Change style on click

Tags: coding-style, onclick

I couldn't get this work. Where do I made a mistake ? I want to add .highligh class when it clicked. And when other one is clicked, remove others' highlight class and add highlight class to clicked one.

```
$("#l1").click(function(){<br>
    $("#l2").removeClass("highlight");<br>
    $("#l3").removeClass("highlight");<br>
    $(this).addClass("highlight");<br>
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to all of your objects for example 'clickable'. Then using $(".clickable") you can access them and handle click event.
Sth like this perhaps:

```
$(".clickable").click(function(){
$(".clickable").removeClass("highlight");
$(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add cssClass to specific element 

$('#element').addClass('myclass');

Remove cssClass from specific element 

$('#element').removeClass('myclass');

Check whether element has the cssClass associated with it 

$('#element').hasClass('myclass');

Add or remove cssClass using single css Selector 

$('#element').toggleClass('myclass');
```